# how to make wait for the Weather API response

Tags: android, weather-api

Here, Toast shows correct weather response from the API but when I return this response to calling function, it gives null.Actually, the response from API takes some time and it returns null before getting the actual response from API.

```
public String weatherStatus(String city) {

    weatherMap.getCityWeather(city, new WeatherCallback() {
        @Override
        public void success(WeatherResponseModel weatherResponseModel) {
            Weather weather[] = weatherResponseModel.getWeather();
            weatherMain = weather[0].getMain();
            Toast.makeText(this,weatherMain,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(String s) {

        }
    });

    return weatherMain;
}
```

So, how to wait for the response from Weather API ??

Comment: Use AysnTask with ProgressDialog

Comment: use `Handler` with method `#postDelay(Runnable run ,Long DelayInMillisec)` and put your code inside the runnable callback.

Comment: I have already tried both handler and Async task but it doesn't work for me. Can you share code.??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you tried implementing this in AsyncTask but you can follow below approach.

```
public class RestManager extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, WeatherResponseModel> implements WeatherCallback{

        private int mStatus;
        private WeatherResponseModel mModel;
        private String mError;
        private Context mContext;

        public RestManager(Context context){
               mContext = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected WeatherResponseModel doInBackground(Void... params) {
            WeatherMap weatherMap = new WeatherMap(mContext, OWM_API_KEY);
            weatherMap.getCityWeather(city, this);
            mStatus = 0;
            while(mStatus==0);//wait for response..
            return mModel;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(WeatherResponseModel weatherResponseModel) {
            super.onPostExecute(weatherResponseModel);
            if(mStatus==1){
                //Success
                Weather weather[] = weatherResponseModel.getWeather();
                weatherMain = weather[0].getMain();
             Toast.makeText(this,weatherMain,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                //Error
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void success(WeatherResponseModel weatherResponseModel) {
            mStatus = 1;
            mModel =  weatherResponseModel;
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(String s) {
            mStatus = -1;
            mError=s;
        }

}
```